# program not executing anything after a call to system()

Tags: c, unix, process

I am calling a command via system(command) call. But no other code is executed after this system() call.

Why is so? I thought, system() would create a child process for "command" execution and my program (parent of "command"-child) will continue executing code after that.

Am I not understanding system() correctly?

code:

```
printf("before \n");
system("tail -f filename");       /* long lived - never returns */
printf("after \n");
```

Here, I do not see after getting printed ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`system(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/system.3.html) function causes your process to wait for the completion of the child.

#### Edit 0:

You have to use the classic pair of [`fork(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) for what you want to do. You might also check whether your C library provides POSIX [`spawn(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawnp).

#### Edit 1:

Look into [`waitpid(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to keep the parent around.

Comment: Thanks much, is there a function where I just create child, let it execute and also continue parent execution?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is system( "tail -f filename&" )

Comment: @William: Thanks :), but now I see interesting behavior: Before putting "&" when I was running my prog, I could see my prog name in "ps" output. Now, with "&", I do not see it in "ps". Why so?

Comment: @hari probably because the program is now running to completion, and by the time you run ps it is already finished

Comment: @Nikolai: Just *realized* that :D, dumb me. Can I keep it running and only end after child ends?

Comment: Using `&` with `system` (actually using `system` whatsoever) is a very very bad idea.

Comment: R: Why? Can you please care to explain? A pointer (to read) would also be fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hari: is `filename` controlled by you, or by users of the program? Have you sanitized your environment (especially `PATH` and `IFS`) before calling `system()`? Don't you think `fork()/exec*()` is easier to get right?

Comment: @ninjail: Sure, I did that and it works fine. I am just a little curious as in, why is there no library function which does fork()/exec*() togather right now.

Comment: @ninjalj: thanks, I dont have that one on my system; anyways, fork()/exec*() is working fine for me. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fork(2) to continue executing code.

Comment: Yep, i just figured out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but here is a solution (tested and working on Linux):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib> //for system()-calls
#include <thread>


//just a utility-function..
template<typename...P> std::string says(P...p)
    {
        std::string r{};
        std::stringstream ss("");
        (ss<<...<<p);
        r=ss.str();
        return r;
    }

#if defined(YOUR_COMPILERS_LINUX_DETECTION_FLAG)
template<typename...T> void _S_R_A_(const std::string &sc)
    {
        std::string s{};
        s=says("nohup ", sc, " 1&2>/dev/null &"); //like old Windows TSR-call
        std::system(s.c_str());
    }
#else // if defined(YOUR_COMPILERS_WINDOWS_DETECTION_FLAG)
template<typename...T> void _S_R_A_(const std::string &sc) //assuming windows - NOT TESTED!
    {
        std::string s{};
        s=says("start ", sc);
        std::system(s.c_str());
    }
#endif

template<typename...T> void SysRunApp(const std::string &sApp, T...t)
    {
        std::string sa{};
        sa=says(sa, sApp, " ", t...); //caller must ensure parameters are
                                      //correctly spaced/escaped etc
        std::thread(_S_R_A_, sa).detach();
    }
```