# Run a Programm with C and go on

Tags: c

Im wondering why my Programm pauses after executing a programm.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf ("Welcome to the Programm\n");
    system ("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StreamCompanion\\osu!StreamCompanion.exe\"");
    printf ("Hopefully that worked\n");
    sleep(5);
}
```

I successfully made it that it runs that Programm, Yes!

But it would not respond this message: `Hopefully that worked`

The Programm pauses in the Background until the executed Programm is closed!

after that the message goes out!

Thanks for ongoing Help! c:

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `system`? It doesn't return until the execution of the command is finished

Comment: For Windows, you can use one of the variations of the [`spawn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=msvc-160) function. The link has example usage.

Comment: @UnholySheep if im not to stupid to find it rn, i would xD

Comment: @SillySoon: What platform (operating system, compiler) are you using?

Comment: In my ide , I didn't find "slep" as reserves word in C language

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Im compiling with GCC since were using it in school for raspbian systems
I am using Windows 10

Comment: @MEDLDN si could also delete the sleep, it works tho bcs i included `#include<unistd.h>`

Comment: @SillySoon: For Linux, you can find the documentation for `system` [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). For Windows, when using Microsoft Visual Studio, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-160). I'm not sure which one applies when using gcc under Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to not wait for a system() command to finish? (in c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962156/is-there-a-way-to-not-wait-for-a-system-command-to-finish-in-c)

Comment: @WeatherVane im totally new to coding and somehow this confuses me even more qwq

Comment: @YurySchkatula if i put `start` in my code like this: `system ("start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StreamCompanion\\osu!StreamCompanion.exe\"");` it creates a new CMD in the file direction.The Main Programm goes on but still, the new CMD is on forever and doesnt even run the Programm im trying to run qwq (I'm just stupid)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand many of your abbreviations. What does "run qwq" mean? Please type in English, not in textspeak.

Comment: @WeatherVane The Main Programm starts and opens a new CMD because of the `start` in `int a = system ("start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StreamCompanion\\osu!StreamCompanion.exe\" &");`, The new CMD doenst do anything.

The Programm Main Programm closes after opening the CMD.

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteA(0, 0, "c:\\dir\\path name.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOW)` if you want to return, followed by `Sleep(1000)`, needs windows.h

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That worked and helped! Thanks a lot <3 Can i please type it as an awnser that i can close this issue? c:

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I think `#include <unistd.h>` is linux specific. I would remove it and use `Sleep(milli_seconds)` instead. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani im using GCC, i also removed it and as u suggested put in `Sleep(milli_seconds)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is operating system specific. In Windows you can use `ShellExecute` to run the program without waiting for it to complete. If your application is exiting immediately after launching the other application, a short `Sleep` is sometimes required at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    printf("Welcome to the Programm\n");
    ShellExecuteA(
        NULL, NULL,
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StreamCompanion\\osu!StreamCompanion.exe",
        NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    printf("Hopefully that worked\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Use `ShellExecuteW(..., L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StreamCompanion"...)` for Unicode names.