# Running two system commands from a c++ program and wait for both to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a C++ program and at some point I need the outputs of two other programs runned with dynamically defined arguments.
At the moment I run both external programs as in the following example:

```
...
system("prog1 arg1".c_str());
system("prog2 arg2".c_str());

if(output1_exist() && output2_exist()){
  data1 = loadoutput1();
  data2 = loadoutput2();
  dosomething(data1, data2);
} else {
  cerr << "error" << endl;
  exit(1);
}
...
```

The point is that both external programs can run for a very long time, so I was thinking to run them concurrently and use a while loop and sleep to wait for both to finish:

```
...
system("prog1 arg1 &".c_str());
system("prog2 arg2 &".c_str());

while(true){
  if(output1_exist() && output2_exist()){
    break;
  } else {
    sleep(60);
  }
}

data1 = loadoutput1();
data2 = loadoutput2();

dosomething(data1, data2);
...
```

The problem with this approach is that if one or both external programs fail for whatever reason I will be locked in the while loop forever.
To avoid this problem I was thinking to use two threads like in the following example:

```
...
void runextprog(string command){
  system(command.c_str())
}

...

vector < thread > threadVect;

threadVect.clear();
threadVect.emplace_back(runextprog, "prog1 arg1");
threadVect.emplace_back(runextprog, "prog2 arg2");

threadVect[0].join();
threadVect[1].join();

if(output1_exist() && output2_exist()){
  data1 = loadoutput1();
  data2 = loadoutput2();
  dosomething(data1, data2);
} else {
  cerr << "error" << endl;
  exit(1);
}
...
```

This should work but to me it seems a little overengenired.

So, can someone suggest me a way to do what I'm looking for in a more elegant and simple way?
I'm working on a multicore linux workstation and I'll probably run my program always in a similar setup, but a portable solution that can run also on win/mac machines will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [program not executing anything after a call to system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552712/program-not-executing-anything-after-a-call-to-system)

Comment: hmm, my link might be unix specific... you're solution doesn't seem bad... or you need to find another way to detect program failure... a timeout or so.

Comment: Hi @JHBonarius, thank you for your time. I'm looking at your link, but it seems a c and *nix specific answer. It should work, but I'd like to wait if someone else has a more portable and more c++ idiomatic way.

Comment: If you need portability you might want to look at [boost.process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/process.html).

Comment: I'm not sure which C++ version do you use. But to model async tasks I would suggest to use co_await - it's very good to model async stuff.

Comment: Hi @G.M., Thank you for your help. I'll take a look at boost.process and I'll try to figure out if I can run two process without waiting for both to finish.

Comment: Thank you @Bernd for your suggestion. IIRC co_await is a C++20 specific keyword and I'm stuck with C++14 at the moment, but I'll check it anyway.